# Saving oAuth credentials

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm using the code from Google Docs as follows to manage Google calendar.

```
public class CalendarQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FOLDER = "credentials"; // Directory to store user credentials.

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_DIR = "client_secret.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If there is no client_secret.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = CalendarQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRET_DIR);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(CREDENTIALS_FOLDER)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Events events = service.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Upcoming events");
            for (Event event : items) {
                DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start == null) {
                    start = event.getStart().getDate();
                }
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", event.getSummary(), start);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I took this and put it in a Java app on the Google App Engine. However, the app isn't able to write credentials to the `credentials` directory as App Engine doesn't allow writing to disk.

One option to overcome this is to write a custom implemenation of `FileDataStoreFactory` and store the credentials in Google Bucket. Is that the recommended appoarch? Is it safe to do so? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

There's a page dedicated to Using [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine) and it also mentions how to connect to other Google APIs like Google Calendar using `OAuth2Decorator` or  `OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets`.

> The easiest way to handle OAuth 2.0 is to use the App Engine Python
>   decorators supplied by this library. These decorators handle all of
>   the OAuth 2.0 steps without you having to use any Flow, Credentials,
>   or Storage objects.
>
> There are two decorator classes to choose from:
>
> **OAuth2Decorator**: Use the OAuth2Decorator class to contruct a decorator
>   with your client ID and secret. **OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets**: Use
>   the OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets class to contruct a decorator
>   using a client_secrets.json file described in the
>   flow_from_clientsecrets() section of the OAuth 2.0 page. There are
>   also two decorator types to choose from:
>
> **oauth_required**: Any method decorated with oauth_required completes all
>   OAuth 2.0 steps before entering the function. Within the body of the
>   function, you can use the decorator's http() function to get an Http
>   object that has already been authorized. oauth_aware: This decorator
>   type requires a little more code than oauth_required, but it is
>   preferred because it gives you control over the user experience. For
>   example, you can display a page explaining why the user is being
>   redirected to an authorization server. This decorator does not perform
>   any OAuth 2.0 steps, but within the body of the decorated function you
>   can call these convenient decorator functions: has_credentials():
>   Returns True if there are valid access credentials for the logged in
>   user. authorize_url(): Returns the first URL that starts the OAuth 2.0
>   steps.

Comment: Thanks @noogui. Is there a Java equivalent for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can head to this site making reference to [how to handle OAuth 2.0 with the App Engine client library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2). This would be the equivalent of @noogui's solution using Java.

Here it is stated that the `GoogleCredential` utility class is used for doing OAuth 2.0 authorization with Google services:

> Google APIs support OAuth 2.0 flows for different types of client applications. In all of these flows, the client application requests an access token that is associated with only your client application and the owner of the protected data being accessed. The access token is also associated with a limited scope that defines the kind of data your client application has access to (for example "Manage your tasks"). An important goal for OAuth 2.0 is to provide secure and convenient access to the protected data, while minimizing the potential impact if an access token is stolen.

There is an [authorization code flow](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#authorization_code_flow) that has to be followed to allow end-users to grant access to protected data to their applications. This would be valid for both web server applications or those from App Engine.

It also includes an example on how to configure the application for using [Calendar from App Engine](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-appengine-sample).